# Null Reference Type with OneTimeSetUp

Tags: c#, nunit

Is possible to use

```
<Nullable>enable</Nullable>
```

in projects developed in nunit that uses fields that are initialized in OneTimeSetup without getting
"warning CS8618: Non-nullable field '...' must contain a non-null value when exiting constructor. Consider declaring the field as nullable.".

I expected to be an annotation like [NotNull] for fields that I initialize in OneTimeSetup, but didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One (somewhat unpleasant!) way is to use the null forigiving operator:

```cs
private string _setInOneTimeSetUp = null!;

[OneTimeSetUp]
public void OneTimeSetUp()
{
    _setInOneTimeSetUp = "value used in tests";
}
```

This compiles with both `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` and `<TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors>`. Given NUnit will always call `OneTimeSetUp` before anything else, it is logically safe, but any time you're using the null forgiving operator is a bit of a code smell.